# C++ terminate called without an active exception (gdb)

Tags: c++, xcode

Using iOS 5.X
Cpp 11
Xcode

I am trying to identify what is causing this error.
It may be caused from destructor being called prior to a thread completing.

```
// default_delete
```

```
template <class _Tp>
struct _LIBCPP_VISIBLE default_delete
{
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY default_delete() _NOEXCEPT {}
    template <class _Up>
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY default_delete(const default_delete<_Up>&,
         typename enable_if<is_convertible<_Up*, _Tp*>::value>::type* = 0) _NOEXCEPT {}
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY void operator() (_Tp* __ptr) const _NOEXCEPT
    {
        static_assert(sizeof(_Tp) > 0, "default_delete can not delete incomplete type"); 
        delete __ptr;
    }
};
```

The stack trace is as follows:

```
stack trace
```

```
2013-01-28 13:50:33.704 CPP11AudioRecoClient[4633:5107] A task has completed. Map now contains 0 entries.
terminate called without an active exception(gdb) bt

#0  0x316e932c in __pthread_kill
#1  0x33de620e in pthread_kill 
#2  0x33ddf29e in abort 
#3  0x36c6cf6a in abort_message 
#4  0x36c6a35a in default_terminate
#5  0x35237324 in _objc_terminate
#6  0x31997c96 in std::terminate
#7  0x319d3d18 in std::__1::thread::~thread ()
#8  0x00076cce in std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::thread>::operator() () at /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/c++/v1/memory:2512

#9  0x319d3d18 in std::__1::thread::~thread ()
#10 0x319d3d18 in std::__1::thread::~thread ()
#11 0x319c94cc in std::__1::__shared_weak_count::__release_shared ()
#12 0x00077606 in std::__1::shared_ptr<std::__1::thread>::~shared_ptr (this=0x2d64c4) at memory:4441
#13 0x0007676c in std::__1::shared_ptr<std::__1::thread>::~shared_ptr (this=0x2d64c4) at memory:4439
#14 0x00076038 in Microsoft::BingMobile::MusicReco::ClientSDK::Cpp11Thread::~Cpp11Thread (this=0x2d64c0) at /Users/v-mattkn/Desktop/CPP11AudioRecoClient/Cpp11ThreadFactory.cpp:125
#15 0x00075ffc in Microsoft::BingMobile::MusicReco::ClientSDK::Cpp11Thread::~Cpp11Thread (this=0x2d64c0) at /Users/v-mattkn/Desktop/CPP11AudioRecoClient/Cpp11ThreadFactory.cpp:123
#16 0x00075fdc in Microsoft::BingMobile::MusicReco::ClientSDK::Cpp11Thread::~Cpp11Thread (this=0x2d64c0) at /Users/v-mattkn/Desktop/CPP11AudioRecoClient/Cpp11ThreadFactory.cpp:123
#17 0x00077f68 in std::__1::default_delete<Microsoft::BingMobile::MusicReco::ClientSDK::Cpp11Thread>::operator() () at /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/c++/v1/memory:2512
#18 0x00077f68 in std::__1::__shared_ptr_pointer<Microsoft::BingMobile::MusicReco::ClientSDK::Cpp11Thread*, std::__1::default_delete<Microsoft::BingMobile::MusicReco::ClientSDK::Cpp11Thread>, std::__1::allocator<Microsoft::BingMobile::MusicReco::ClientSDK::Cpp11Thread> >::__on_zero_shared (this=0x2d5280) at memory:3668
#19 0x319c94cc in std::__1::__shared_weak_count::__release_shared ()
#20 0x0006a86e in std::__1::shared_ptr<Microsoft::BingMobile::MusicReco::ClientSDK::IThread>::~shared_ptr (this=0x2d6478) at memory:4441
#21 0x00069d94 in std::__1::shared_ptr<Microsoft::BingMobile::MusicReco::ClientSDK::IThread>::~shared_ptr (this=0x2d6478) at memory:4439
#22 0x00068d56 in Microsoft::BingMobile::MusicReco::ClientSDK::AsyncTask::~AsyncTask (this=0x2d6460) at /Users/v-mattkn/Desktop/CPP11AudioRecoClient/AsyncTask.cpp:34
#23 0x00068ce8 in Microsoft::BingMobile::MusicReco::ClientSDK::AsyncTask::~AsyncTask (this=0x2d6460) at /Users/v-mattkn/Desktop/CPP11AudioRecoClient/AsyncTask.cpp:33
#24 0x00068cc8 in Microsoft::BingMobile::MusicReco::ClientSDK::AsyncTask::~AsyncTask (this=0x2d6460) at /Users/v-mattkn/Desktop/CPP11AudioRecoClient/AsyncTask.cpp:33
#25 0x0006ad08 in std::__1::default_delete<Microsoft::BingMobile::MusicReco::ClientSDK::AsyncTask>::operator() () at /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/c++/v1/memory:2512
#26 0x0006ad08 in std::__1::__shared_ptr_pointer<Microsoft::BingMobile::MusicReco::ClientSDK::AsyncTask*, std::__1::default_delete<Microsoft::BingMobile::MusicReco::ClientSDK::AsyncTask>, std::__1::allocator<Microsoft::BingMobile::MusicReco::ClientSDK::AsyncTask> >::__on_zero_shared (this=0x2d6090) at memory:3668
#27 0x319c94cc in std::__1::__shared_weak_count::__release_shared ()
#28 0x00069fca in std::__1::shared_ptr<Microsoft::BingMobile::MusicReco::ClientSDK::ITaskObserver>::~shared_ptr (this=0x44fb4fc) at memory:4441
#29 0x00069e6c in std::__1::shared_ptr<Microsoft::BingMobile::MusicReco::ClientSDK::ITaskObserver>::~shared_ptr (this=0x44fb4fc) at memory:4439
#30 0x00099c22 in Microsoft::BingMobile::MusicReco::ClientSDK::RunnableTaskBase::notifyObserver (this=0x2d6350, observerWeak=<value temporarily unavailable, due to optimizations>, sharedReferenceToSelf=@0x44fb638) at /Users/v-mattkn/Desktop/CPP11AudioRecoClient/RunnableTaskBase.cpp:100
#31 0x00099930 in Microsoft::BingMobile::MusicReco::ClientSDK::RunnableTaskBase::notifyObservers (this=0x2d6350, sharedReferenceToSelf=<value temporarily unavailable, due to optimizations>) at /Users/v-mattkn/Desktop/CPP11AudioRecoClient/RunnableTaskBase.cpp:79
#32 0x000996e0 in Microsoft::BingMobile::MusicReco::ClientSDK::RunnableTaskBase::setStatus (this=0x2d6350, targetStatus=Microsoft::BingMobile::MusicReco::ClientSDK::Completed, sharedReferenceToSelf=@0x44fbd20) at /Users/v-mattkn/Desktop/CPP11AudioRecoClient/RunnableTaskBase.cpp:107
#33 0x00087168 in Microsoft::BingMobile::MusicReco::ClientSDK::PingWebServiceTask::runTaskChecked (this=0x2d6350, sharedReferenceToSelf=<value temporarily unavailable, due to optimizations>) at /Users/v-mattkn/Desktop/CPP11AudioRecoClient/PingWebServiceTask.cpp:120
#34 0x00099356 in Microsoft::BingMobile::MusicReco::ClientSDK::RunnableTaskBase::runTask (this=0x2d6350) at /Users/v-mattkn/Desktop/CPP11AudioRecoClient/RunnableTaskBase.cpp:60
#35 0x000991d2 in Microsoft::BingMobile::MusicReco::ClientSDK::RunnableTaskBase::run (this=0x2d6350, sharedReferenceToSelf=<value temporarily unavailable, due to optimizations>) at /Users/v-mattkn/Desktop/CPP11AudioRecoClient/RunnableTaskBase.cpp:48
#36 0x00099250 in non-virtual thunk to Microsoft::BingMobile::MusicReco::ClientSDK::RunnableTaskBase::run(std::__1::shared_ptr<Microsoft::BingMobile::MusicReco::ClientSDK::IRunnable>) () at memory:4023
#37 0x000759ca in Microsoft::BingMobile::MusicReco::ClientSDK::RunHookedRunnable::run (this=0x2d64a0, sharedReferenceToSelf=@0x44fcea8) at /Users/v-mattkn/Desktop/CPP11AudioRecoClient/Cpp11ThreadFactory.cpp:75
#38 0x0007736e in _ZNKSt3__110unique_ptrINS_5tupleIJMN9Microsoft10BingMobile9MusicReco9ClientSDK9IRunnableEFvNS_10shared_ptrIS6_EEES8_S8_EEENS_14default_deleteISB_EEEdeEv [inlined] () at /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/c++/v1/memory:309
#39 0x0007736e in _ZNSt3__114__thread_proxyINS_5tupleIJMN9Microsoft10BingMobile9MusicReco9ClientSDK9IRunnableEFvNS_10shared_ptrIS6_EEES8_S8_EEEEEPvSC_ (__vp=0x2d6230) at __functional_base:340
```

## 40 0x33da7734 in _pthread_start ()

Comment: Don't use names that start with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter (`_Tp`) or names that contain two consecutive underscores. They're reserved to the implementation. If `_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY` is provided by your compiler/runtime library it's okay.

Comment: that code is provided by the compiler. in <memory> just the snippet of code that throws the sigabrt. Having a hard time tracking down the root of this issue

Comment: Okay. In fact, I probably wrote it (but without the `_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY` stuff).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That `thread::~thread()` in the backtrace suggests that the thread is still running when it's object gets destroyed. That's an error; you have to call `join()` or `detach()` on the thread object before destroying it.

Comment: Excellent good call! I had a destructor that was being called. I simply add an if to detach the thread before destroying.

Comment: Glad to hear that that helps. Is detaching really the right answer? Sure, it makes the problem go away, but detached threads are somewhat unusual, and should be part of the design.